# How to get token index map from tf hub pre-trained embedding?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I'm trying to use tfhub pre-trained word embedding in a text generation project. The setting is that there is a corpus of English text. I want to convert each word to dense vector (embedding) and then feed the sequence to a LSTM model and try to learn how to generate next word given a sequence.

Initially I was trying to load the embedding as a KerasLayer.

```
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[],
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True, name='embedding')
```

However, the KerasLayer doesn't seem to take sequences as input which is 2D. It looks like I have to preprocess the text, tokenize and convert each token to vector, and then feed the vector directly to a LSTM layer.

In this case, I will need to use token to int mapping from the model. I located the tokens.txt file in the assets directory from local cache.

```
./tf_cache/510580b203329a4a95dfdfefd838bdcd202f0d13/assets/tokens.txt
```

But I don't want to manually copy the file out and load it to memory. Is there an API from tensorflow that I can call to get the token mapping instead of reading the file manually?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manipulate the tensors so that you can pass it into the KerasLayer.

If you are using ragged tensors  `tf.ragged.map_flat_values` is your friend, e.g.:

```py
sentences = ["sentence 1", "sentence number 2"]
words = tf.strings.split(sentences)
word_embeddings = tf.ragged.map_flat_values(hub_layer, words)
word_embeddings.to_tensor()  # Convert to dense now to feed into next layers.
```

If you already have a dense tensor of shape [num_sentences, num_words], you could reshape it to a [num_sentences*num_words], then embed it transforming it into [num_sentences*num_words, embedding_size] and then you could reshape back into [num_sentences, num_words, embedding_size]. In this case `tf.reshape` is your friend.

Something like:

```py
dense_features = tf.constant([["sentence", "with", "four", "words"], ["hello", "world", "", ""]])

# Reshape to 1-d tensor.
flatten_words = tf.reshape(tokenized_dense_sentences, [-1])

# Embed each element as if it was a single batch of words.
flatten_word_embeddings = hub_layer(flatten_words)

# Reshape back to 3-d tensor.
num_sentences = tf.shape(dense_features)[0]
max_num_words = tf.shape(dense_features)[1]
embedded_features = tf.reshape(flatten_word_embeddings, [num_sentences, max_num_words, -1])
```

These examples differ on how they treat the non existent words.

Comment: Your method will convert data to [num_sentences, num_words, embedding_size]. Let's say there is a LSTM layer with 512 hidden units. And then a dense layer with num_vocab output. The downstream output shape will be [num_sentences, num_vocab]. Now the label data is of shape [num_sentences, num_words, embedding_size], which is not comparable to the output shape. How do you make the loss function work? Maybe we can convert each vocab to vector and then implement the categorical crossentropy function. But then you will need the vocabulary anyways. Did I understand the system correctly?